# Which SFF movie or TV series first showed Hitler?

Tags: history-of

Hitler is very famous in fiction world and SFF is no exception. For example, Captain America Comics has shown Hitler countless times since early 40s. But, I am only interested in the movie and TV series. Some examples:

- In the episode *Let's Kill Hitler* of *Doctor Who* (2005), Hitler was shown.
- In an episode of *Justice League* (2001) in which Justice League travelled back in time to restore timeline, Hitler was shown frozen in the end.

**Note:** Mere mention of Hitler (like that in *Captain America: The First Avenger* movie) won't be counted.

Comment: Does Disney propaganda cartoons count?

Comment: @Yasskier Which propaganda cartoon?

Comment: There are 10 here: https://listverse.com/2017/02/05/10-disney-propaganda-cartoons-from-world-war-ii I've picked two with Hitler itself. They are arguably SFF (fantastic machines, fantasy hell etc).

Comment: They've Shown him in a Red dwarf Episode I do believe but forget the episode. It was where they were on a planet that had a bunch of robots all set up to look like different figures.

Comment: If only the [The Great Dictator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Dictator) was SFF!

Comment: The [Adolf Hitler in popular culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler_in_popular_culture) article seems to contain all of the references so far put forward (but none earlier)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From a close look into [Adolf Hitler in popular culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler_in_popular_culture) there is:

[Bosko's Picture Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosko%27s_Picture_Show)

> Bosko's Picture Show was released on August 26, 1933, though at least
>   one source claims the release date is September 18, 1933. It was
>   the last Looney Tunes Bosko cartoon produced by Hugh Harman and Rudolf
>   Ising for Leon Schlesinger and Warner Bros.

And (my emphasis)

> The final scene of the newsreel takes place in "Pretzel, Germany",
>   where Adolf Hitler is depicted pursuing Jimmy Durante with a meat
>   cleaver or axe in hand. Hitler is depicted as a ruthless and violent
>   buffoon, wearing lederhosen and an armband depicting a swastika.
>   Durante shouts the phrase "Am I mortified!". **Aside from newsreels,
>   this is argued to be the first depiction of Hitler in an American
>   film.**

But then the article goes on to say:

> However there is an earlier appearance in Cubby's World Flight
>   (August, 1933) by the Van Beuren Studios. While flying over Germany,
>   Cubby Bear receives smiles and waves from both Chancellor Hitler and
>   President Paul von Hindenburg

[Cubby's World Flight (1933)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146594/)

[Aesop's fables World Flight featuring Cubby Bear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBrZhBLT77Y)

Comment: Hollywood's relationship with nazi Germany was interesting. Germany was of course a market for its films but also the Jews who had founded many of the studios were not happy with the nazi "racial" policies and indeed iirc a Jewish employee of one of the studios was murdered in the mid 30s by nazi thugs. Furthermore, Goebbels was trying to reduce German consumption of films made by/with Jews and made its own antisemitic flicks. Interestingly, Thalberg did travel to Germany for surgery despite the nazis because of the superiority of German medicine.

Answer (score 13):

The other two answers address the *first movie*.  This answer addresses the ***first TV series*** aspect of the question.

According to the list [Adolf Hitler in popular culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler_in_popular_culture), the first three appearances of Hitler on a television all occurred on *The Twilight Zone:*

> In "The Man in the Bottle," a man (Luther Adler) who has been granted four wishes by a genie wishes himself to be a leader of a country who cannot be voted out of office, only to find he is Hitler and it is the end of World War II. He quickly uses his final wish to be restored to normal. In "He's Alive", Hitler appears to help a struggling Neo-Nazi (Dennis Hopper) gain more followers. In "No Time Like the Past," a time traveler (Dana Andrews) tries to assassinate Hitler in 1939 but is stopped when a suspicious maid brings the SS to his hotel room.

The first of these episodes aired October 7, 1960.  That's after the films of the other answers, but it is the first *television* appearance.

Answer (score 12):

Devil with Hitler (1942) - a live action movie (only fragment available on Youtube):

In the pits of Hell, the board of directors decides to replace Satan (Alan Mowbray) with Adolf Hitler (Bobby Watson). Satan persuades them to give him 48 hours to save his job by getting Hitler to perform a single good deed.

Satan arranges for Hitler's valet, Julius (Sig Arno), to appear to blunder several times, resulting in his replacement. Satan takes his place under the name "Gesatan".

Donald Duck Nazi (1943)

This one shows how lucky you are to live in a free country instead of Nazi Germany.

Both movies are arguably SFF - you have impossible, fantastic machines and well... Hell.

Adolf Hitler Goes to Hell (1944 ?)

It was a propaganda cartoon, showing Hitler driving tiny tanks. Unfortunately for Fuhrer, he messes up with wrong guys and ends up in hell.

Another one (kudos to Clockwork): Daffy the Commando

Comment: I remember a Looney Tunes-ish cartoon I saw when I was a kid. It ended with some kind of duck (Daffy?) hitting Hitler(?) on the head with a hammer. Can't remember how it was called, but the colors looked old enough. I think it was part of a VHS box with Porky on it.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. It's "Daffy – The Commando", which came out on 20th November 1943. Several months after Donald Duck Nazi though.

Comment: Two of the video links in this answer have gone dead.

Comment: @Randal'Thor fixed, at least partially: I can't find full version of the missing movies on  legitimate sites

Comment: You should put the earliest first, so it establishes the overall precedence of your answer.